# Uploaded image doesn't show up in media library

Tags: uploads

So, I'm uploading an image file which works with the following code however, it does not appear in the Media Library. I get a "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded" message but I must be missing a step.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

$files = array('tmp_name' => $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'],
            'name' => $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']);



$overrides = array( 'test_form' => false,
                'action' => 'to_be',
                'mimes' => false);

$movefile = @wp_handle_upload( $files, $overrides );

if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

} else {
/**
 * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
 * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
 */
echo $movefile['error'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing element that makes a file appear in the media library is the attachment post. Attachment posts hold the file metadata, and are what get associated to posts via the `post_parent` when a file is "attached".

Instead of `wp_handle_upload`, you can use the function [`media_handle_upload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload), which will handle the file upload as well as insert the attachment post.

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong 150%! WP media does not check if image exists in his stupid, poorly coded, media library! So metadatas are good but the file may not exist, wp never checks anything beside the metadata field (...). SO: You MUST NOT USE WP TO UPLOAD your image because it might rename it if it already exists in his stuipd media library (by adding a stupid image-1 number to it, without telling you). It will also give this image a new unique ID. Finally you will end up with a new image and still have the wrong one in the metadata fields. Yeah wp media is the worst thing you can use to handle medias. If you delete the image from tjhe media library then you lose all reference in all posts or pages you were using it... Yeahhh nice job!